# Import every 50th record from a data file

Tags: import, data

I want to import a really big data file which seems like it is too big for Mathematica. That's why I want to import the data in parts. For example, if I have 15,000 rows of data then I would read in only every 50th during import.

Is something like this possible? If you have something which can help me please let me know.

Comment: It seems like you are asking about MatLab. This is a site for the computing software *Mathematica*. Did you actually mean to ask about *Mathematica*?

Comment: Updated to say that it's about Mathematica after clarification from OP in a now deleted answer.

Comment: What's the structure of the data? Or at least show us the file.

Comment: I don't think 15 000 records will be too large for Mathematica.

Comment: We need to know what format the data is in. The answer differs depending on the format - for instance, `csv` vs `hdf`.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime ago I wrote a fairly general file filtering function. It uses low-level file system functions and is easily adapted to your problem by writing and passing a simple filter function to it.

The file filtering function goes like this:

```
filterFile::"bad path" = "Input file `1` not found.";
filterFile[infile_String, outfile_String, filter_] :=
  If[FileType[infile] === File,
    Module[{instream = OpenRead[infile], outstream = OpenWrite[outfile]},
      filter[instream, outstream];
    AbortProtect[Close[outfile]; Close[infile]]],
  Message[filterFile::"bad path", infile]]
```

A filter suited to your problem would look like this:

```
filter[instream_InputStream, outstream_OutputStream] :=
  Module[{counter = 0, span = 10, line},
    While[(line = ReadLine[instream]) =!= EndOfFile,
      counter = Mod[counter + 1, span];
      If[counter == 0, WriteLine[outstream, line]]];]
```

You will need to set `span` to 50; I am using `10` to filter a contrived dataset that will serve as a test example.

Contrived data: 100 records each containing a record number and four random reals.

```
data = Join[List /@ Range[100], RandomReal[1., {100, 4}], 2];
dir = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop"}];
Export[FileNameJoin[{dir, "data.csv"}], data];
```

The export produces a file that looks this:

> ```
> 1,0.6072789924993369,0.02761223697367554,0.7706229552970443,0.10477948568009632
> 2,0.5272754697910746,0.42152331274590793,0.15626294269475083,0.5862035931443668
> 3,0.6222386112567269,0.2770935554617886,0.7724384312268242,0.29350522059233186
> ...
> 98,0.703725939386822,0.1842671376693752,0.3035129060347801,0.7029751749054369
> 99,0.9771554318986615,0.9071157038423141,0.9707621125489199,0.1881392381139697
> 100,0.9688258886649075,0.35118493536477136,0.1000208001830043,0.06290674968843235
> ```

The filtering is accomplished with this code:

```
filterFile[
  FileNameJoin[{dir, "data.csv"}], 
  FileNameJoin[{dir, "filtered.csv"}], 
  filter]
```

It produces a .csv file that looks like this:

> ```
> 10,0.3370950525296681,0.5336534761347127,0.3436324966270312,0.8263774950648604
> 20,0.1243026990830216,0.1160969373343923,0.7770812362085957,0.5590901453096624
> 30,0.6193217371981197,0.8082945845417391,0.6311047871649496,0.8993054901640238
> 40,0.6324706743029063,0.18286150111395005,0.18878594279850902,0.10636154538152676
> 50,0.5732103848068784,0.576948340386314,0.21174760808475157,0.7865546128971181
> 60,0.44698812232040663,0.8199274651894508,0.30203640330682546,0.16975348218783837
> 70,0.9664535595321413,0.4377553116978592,0.03923904958126356,0.9129190783018555
> 80,0.8393378248032695,0.3551248179377866,0.2411403127768581,0.9777961224028708
> 90,0.32174664903588357,0.3790767495422567,0.1544454155679893,0.46380577023689784
> 100,0.9688258886649075,0.35118493536477136,0.1000208001830043,0.0629067496884323
> ```

All you have to do after making a filtered file is import it in the usual manner.

Answer (score 2):

Read the file "data.txt" into the variable `data`, reading only every 50th line (reading lines 1, 51, 101, etc.):

```
data = Module[{f, d, L},
  f = OpenRead["data.txt"];
  d = Reap[While[(L = Read[f, String]) =!= EndOfFile, Sow[L]; 
        Skip[f, String, 49]]];
  Close[f];
  If[d == {{}}, {}, d[[2, 1]]]]
```

You'll have to modify the third line `L = Read[f, String]` to do the actual line-reading that you want. As it is, it reads the entire line as a single string.

If you want to read lines 50, 100, 150, etc. instead, do this (and modify line 4):

```
data = Module[{f, d, L},
  f = OpenRead["data.txt"];
  d = Reap[While[Skip[f, String, 49];
        (L = Read[f, String]) =!= EndOfFile, Sow[L]]];
  Close[f];
  If[d == {{}}, {}, d[[2, 1]]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If the data is in a CSV or TSV file format, you can use `Import` to get every 50th row directly,

```
file = Export["test.tsv", Thread[{Range[1000], RandomReal[1, 1000]}]];

Import[file, {"Data", 1 ;; -1 ;; 50}]
(* {{1, 0.695758}, {51, 0.805026}, {101, 0.466447}, {151, 
  0.788209}, {201, 0.720255}, {251, 0.915696}, {301, 0.530456}, {351, 
  0.166995}, {401, 0.0383326}, {451, 0.728045}, {501, 0.563912}, {551,
   0.944089}, {601, 0.0629406}, {651, 0.714994}, {701, 
  0.0979508}, {751, 0.299093}, {801, 0.486756}, {851, 0.240574}, {901,
   0.59668}, {951, 0.310183}} *)
```

Comment: Does this import the whole file into the kernel and then select every 50th element, or does it retrieve the 50th elements "out of core"? My fear is that for a sufficiently large file this wouldn't be any more efficient, from what I've seen out of tabular import int the past.

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess the file with [awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```
ReadList["!awk 'NR%50==0' data.txt", String]
```

Replace `String` with whatever patterns you want to read from the file (and of course change the file name from `data.txt`). The preprocessing step then only feeds lines 50, 100, 150, etc. into the `ReadList` function.

If you want lines 1, 51, 101, etc. instead, change `'NR%50==0'` to `'NR%50==1'`.